# "AssertionError: Q2: Your answer is not close enough to ours to be correct."(Introduction to data science in python Coursera)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I need some assistance with my Assignment 4 for Introduction to Data Science in Python.

Question 2 of assignment 4.

> For this question, calculate the win/loss ratio's correlation with the population of the city it is in for the NBA using 2018 data.

When I submit the assignment this is the error i get

> You have failed this test due to an error. The traceback has been removed because it may contain hidden tests. This is the exception
> that was thrown:
>
> AssertionError: Q2: Your answer is not close enough to ours to be
> correct.

The answer I get is

> -0.16087318003059875

I have a feeling the answer must be around

> -0.1763635064218294

since that is what the other online resources show me for people who have taken part in the test,

Here is my Dataframe output:

```
NBA DataFrame:
                         W/L%  Population
Metropolitan area                        
Atlanta                 0.293   5789700.0
Boston                  0.671   4794447.0
Charlotte               0.439   2474314.0
Chicago                 0.329   9512999.0
Cleveland               0.610   2055612.0
Dallas–Fort Worth       0.293   7233323.0
Denver                  0.561   2853077.0
Detroit                 0.476   4297617.0
Houston                 0.793   6772470.0
Indianapolis            0.585   2004230.0
Los Angeles             0.512  13310447.0
Memphis                 0.268   1342842.0
Miami–Fort Lauderdale   0.537   6066387.0
Milwaukee               0.537   1572482.0
Minneapolis–Saint Paul  0.573   3551036.0
New Orleans             0.585   1268883.0
New York City           0.341  20153634.0
Oklahoma City           0.585   1373211.0
Orlando                 0.305   2441257.0
Philadelphia            0.634   6070500.0
Phoenix                 0.256   4661537.0
Portland                0.598   2424955.0
Sacramento              0.329   2296418.0
Salt Lake City          0.585   1186187.0
San Antonio             0.573   2429609.0
San Francisco Bay Area  0.707   6657982.0
Toronto                 0.720   5928040.0
Washington, D.C.        0.524   6131977.0
Correlation Coefficient: -0.16087318003059875
-0.16087318003059875
```

​

This is my solution for question 2 run in Jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import re

cities = pd.read_html("assets/wikipedia_data.html")[1]
cities = cities.iloc[:-1, [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
cities.rename(columns={"Population (2016 est.)[8]": "Population"},
              inplace=True)
cities['NFL'] = cities['NFL'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]", "")
cities['MLB'] = cities['MLB'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]", "")
cities['NBA'] = cities['NBA'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]", "")
cities['NHL'] = cities['NHL'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]", "")

Big4='NBA'

def nba_correlation():
    
    team = cities[Big4].str.extract('([A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*\ [A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*|[A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*)([A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*\ [A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*|[A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*)([A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*\ [A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*|[A-Z]{0,2}[a-z0-9]*)')
    team['Metropolitan area']=cities['Metropolitan area']
    team = pd.melt(team, id_vars=['Metropolitan area']).drop(columns=['variable']).replace("",np.nan).replace("—",np.nan).dropna().reset_index().rename(columns = {"value":"team"})
    team=pd.merge(team,cities,how='left',on = 'Metropolitan area').iloc[:,1:4]
    team = team.astype({'Metropolitan area': str, 'team': str, 'Population': int})
    team['team']=team['team'].str.replace('[\w.]*\ ','')

    _df=pd.read_csv("assets/"+str.lower(Big4)+".csv")
    _df = _df[_df['year'] == 2018]
    _df['team'] = _df['team'].str.replace(r'[\*]',"")
    _df['team'] = _df['team'].str.replace(r'\(\d*\)',"")
    _df['team'] = _df['team'].str.replace(r'[\xa0]',"")
    _df = _df[['team','W/L%']]
    _df['team'] = _df['team'].str.replace('[\w.]* ','')
    _df = _df.astype({'team': str,'W/L%': float})
    
    merge=pd.merge(team,_df,'outer', on = 'team')
    merge=merge.groupby('Metropolitan area').agg({'W/L%': np.nanmean, 'Population': np.nanmean})

    population_by_region = merge['Population'] # pass in metropolitan area population from cities
    win_loss_by_region = merge['W/L%'] # pass in win/loss ratio from _df in the same order as cities["Metropolitan area"]   

    assert len(population_by_region) == len(win_loss_by_region), "Q2: Your lists must be the same length"
    assert len(population_by_region) == 28, "Q2: There should be 28 teams being analysed for NBA"

    return stats.pearsonr(population_by_region, win_loss_by_region)[0]
nba_correlation()
```

I am not so sure how to go with this since am sure i have worked out the assignment to my full capabilities, also below is my question 1 code just in case it cuts across.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import re

def clear_data(string1):
    if re.search(r'\[[a-z]* [0-9]+\]', string1) is None:
        return string1
    else:
        return string1.replace(re.search(r'\[[a-z]* [0-9]+\]', string1).group(), '')

def get_area(team):
    for each in list(nhl_cities.index.values):
        if team in each:
            return nhl_cities.at[each, 'Metropolitan area']

nhl_df=pd.read_csv("assets/nhl.csv")
cities=pd.read_html("assets/wikipedia_data.html")[1]
cities=cities.iloc[:-1,[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
cities['NHL'] = cities['NHL'].apply(lambda x: clear_data(x))
nhl_cities = cities[['Metropolitan area', 'NHL']].set_index('NHL')
nhl_cities = nhl_cities.drop(['—', ''], axis=0)
nhl_df = nhl_df[nhl_df['year'] == 2018].drop([0, 9, 18, 26], axis=0) # get only 2018 stats
population = cities[['Metropolitan area', 'Population (2016 est.)[8]']]
population = population.set_index('Metropolitan area')
nhl_df['team'] = nhl_df['team'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1].strip() if x.endswith("*") else x.strip())
nhl_df['area'] = nhl_df['team'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1])
nhl_df['area'] = nhl_df['area'].apply(lambda x: get_area(x))
out = []
for group, frame in nhl_df.groupby('area'):
    total_wins = np.sum(pd.to_numeric(frame['W']))
    total_losses = np.sum(pd.to_numeric(frame['L']))
    total_matches = total_wins + total_losses
    ratio = total_wins / total_matches
    out_dict = {
        'Area': group,
        'Ratio': ratio
    }
    out.append(out_dict)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(out)
new_df = new_df.set_index('Area')
out_df = pd.merge(new_df, population, how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)
out_df['Population (2016 est.)[8]'] = pd.to_numeric(out_df['Population (2016 est.)[8]'])

def nhl_correlation(): 
    population_by_region = out_df['Population (2016 est.)[8]'].to_list()
    win_loss_by_region = out_df['Ratio'].to_list()

    assert len(population_by_region) == len(win_loss_by_region), "Q1: Your lists must be the same length"
    assert len(population_by_region) == 28, "Q1: There should be 28 teams being analysed for NHL"
    
    return np.float64(stats.pearsonr(population_by_region, win_loss_by_region)[0])

def get_nhl_data():
    return out_df
```

And here is the question to assignment 4.

> In this assignment you must read in a file of
> metropolitan regions and associated sports teams from
> assets/wikipedia_data.html and answer some questions about each
> metropolitan region. Each of these regions may have one or more teams
> from the "Big 4": NFL (football, in assets/nfl.csv), MLB (baseball, in
> assets/mlb.csv), NBA (basketball, in assets/nba.csv or NHL (hockey, in
> assets/nhl.csv). Please keep in mind that all questions are from the
> perspective of the metropolitan region, and that this file is the
> "source of authority" for the location of a given sports team. Thus
> teams which are commonly known by a different area (e.g. "Oakland
> Raiders") need to be mapped into the metropolitan region given (e.g.
> San Francisco Bay Area). This will require some human data
> understanding outside of the data you've been given (e.g. you will
> have to hand-code some names, and might need to google to find out
> where teams are)!
>
> For each sport I would like you to answer the question: what is the
> win/loss ratio's correlation with the population of the city it is in?
> Win/Loss ratio refers to the number of wins over the number of wins
> plus the number of losses. Remember that to calculate the correlation
> with pearsonr, so you are going to send in two ordered lists of
> values, the populations from the wikipedia_data.html file and the
> win/loss ratio for a given sport in the same order. Average the
> win/loss ratios for those cities which have multiple teams of a single
> sport. Each sport is worth an equal amount in this assignment
> (20%*4=80%) of the grade for this assignment. You should only use data
> from year 2018 for your analysis -- this is important!
>
> Notes Do not include data about the MLS or CFL in any of the work you
> are doing, we're only interested in the Big 4 in this assignment. I
> highly suggest that you first tackle the four correlation questions in
> order, as they are all similar and worth the majority of grades for
> this assignment. This is by design! It's fair game to talk with peers
> about high level strategy as well as the relationship between
> metropolitan areas and sports teams. However, do not post code solving
> aspects of the assignment (including such as dictionaries mapping
> areas to teams, or regexes which will clean up names). There may be
> more teams than the assert statements test, remember to collapse
> multiple teams in one city into a single value! As this assignment
> utilizes global variables in the skeleton code, to avoid having errors
> in your code you can either:
>
> You can place all of your code within the function definitions for all
> of the questions (other than import statements). You can create copies
> of all the global variables with the copy() method and proceed as
> usual.

Here is some sample data so one can understand how the data in the CSV files looks like in Jupyter Notebook:

mlb.csv
[image: mlb.csv]

nfl.csv
[image: nfl.csv]

nba.csv
[image: nba.csv]

nhl.csv
[image: nhl.csv]

wikipedia_data.html
[image: wikipedia_data.html]